# I can't get my integers in the right order

Tags: java, loops

I have the part of the code asking the the numbers but I can't get them in the right order that I need. Also I'm not sure how to add them up and display the number of them.

> Problem Statement:
>
> Program that uses one loop to process the integers from 300 down to 200, inclusive. The program should detect multiples of 11 or 13, but not both. The multiples should be printed left-aligned in columns 8 characters wide, 5 multiples per line. When all multiples have been displayed, the program should display the number of multiples found and their sum.

```
package chapter5;

public class Assignment1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 300;
        while (sum >= 200 && sum <= 300 ) {
            if((sum % 11 == 0) != (sum % 13 == 0)) { 
                System.out.print(sum + " ");
            }
            sum = sum - 1;  
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
299 297 275 273 264 260 253 247 242 234 231 221 220 209 208
```

Comment: Please show what you would expect the output to be if your program were working as intended.

Comment: 8 characters wide, 5 multiples per line, sounds like a contradiction to me.  For matches in the hundreds, you could fit at most two numbers in a single line before you would use up 8 characters.

Comment: The variable called `sum` isn't a sum, it's just the number you're testing and should be called something else, like `n` or `num`.  You still do need something that should properly be called `sum`, though, because the assignment calls for you to print the sum of all the multiples you found...

Comment: @Tim "8 characters wide" means each number in a field 8 characters wide, as I read it. That would allow 5 of them to fit in 40 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can start with a `List<Integer>` to collect your *multiples*. Loop over the values you've been given. Test if each value is a multiple of 11 **xor** 13. If so, add it to a sum variable, and to your `List`. Then iterate the `List`, print each value left aligned and add a line break every fifth line. Then display the count (size of the `List`) and `sum`. Something like,

```
int sum = 0;
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 300; i >= 200; i--) {
    if ((i % 11 == 0) ^ (i % 13) == 0) {
        al.add(i);
        sum += i;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-8d", al.get(i));
    if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
System.out.printf("Found %d multiples, with a sum of %d.%n", al.size(), sum);
```

Which outputs

```
299     297     275     273     264     
260     253     247     242     234     
231     221     220     209     208     
Found 15 multiples, with a sum of 3733.
```

**or** with one loop and no `List` like,

```
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 300; i >= 200; i--) {
    if ((i % 11 == 0) ^ (i % 13) == 0) {
        System.out.printf("%-8d", i);
        count++;
        sum += i;
        if (count % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
System.out.printf("Found %d multiples, with a sum of %d.%n", count, sum);
```

For the same output.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain fixed-width columns, use the following to print each number each number:

```
System.out.printf("%-8d", sum);
```

To print 5 columns per line, you need to keep a column counter.  Start it off at zero.  Each time you print a number, increment the column counter.  When it reaches 5, do `System.out.println();` to start a new line, and reset the column count to zero.

Answer (score 0):

As the loop runs among 3 digited numbers so only add a tab after each number found while printing and print a new line after five iterations of the loop.

```
package chapter5;


public class Assignment1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i= 300,c=0,sum=0,multiples=0;
    while (i>= 200 && i<= 300 ) {
        if((i% 11 == 0) != (i% 13 == 0)) { 
            System.out.print(i+ "\t");
            c++;
            multiples++;
            sum+=i;
        }
        if(c==5){
            System.out.println();
            c=0;
        }
        i--; 
    }
    System.out.println();//TO print the sum in the matrix remove this line.

    System.out.print("Found "+multiples+" and sum = "+sum);
}
}

//If the loop gets in to 2 digit number then update the line
//System.out.print(i+ " \t");
// \t = tab space = 5 white space.
```

Comment: Sorry I'm Still new to java, what does the " \t " mean

Comment: @michael It means a tab character.

Comment: It means tab a white space character made up of 5 spaces. It is like 5 spaces stitched together.

Comment: And i have mentioned it in the end of the program too and if the answer is correct for u please accept my answer.